# Excel VBA For-Loop skipping some files, but not others

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running an Excel VBA macro. It includes the following code:

```
Private Sub ListTheFiles(inFldr as Scripting.Folder)
   Dim fl as Scripting.File, subfldr as Scripting.Folder

   If inFldr.Files.Count > 0 then
       For Each fl in inFldr.Files
          'List the file and its size and LastModifiedDate on a worksheet, making no changes to the file
       Next fl
   End If

   For Each subfldr in inFldr.Subfolders
       ListTheFiles subfldr
   Next subfldr
End Sub
```

The module runs this subroutine hundreds of times, usually successfully. But for just a couple of folders, it reaches the first "For Each" (which indicates there ARE files in inFldr), but then it skips right to the "End If" without processing any files. The two folders that don't get processed each contains 12 PDF files and no other files and no subfolders. Many of the other folders also contain PDF files only, and they work fine.

Why would this happen? Thanks.

Comment: Is `inFldr.Files.Count` equal to the number of files in each of the problem folders?  Are those specific folders always skipped?

Comment: Could you share the (a) code which is calling this procedure?

Answer (score 0):

### List Files in a Folder and in Its Subfolders

- I am using this without a reference to the `Scripting FileSystemObject` object. As you can see, the 'recursion' code is 'basically' the same (except for the `.Count`). You could test it, to see if the issue repeats itself.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilesRecurseTEST()
    Const FolderPath As String = "F:\Test\2021"
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FilesRecurse fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
End Sub

Sub FilesRecurse( _
        fsoFolder As Object)
    Dim fsoSubFolder As Object, fsoFile As Object
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
        With fsoFile
            Debug.Print .Name, .Size, .DateLastModified
        End With
    Next fsoFile
    For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoFolder.Subfolders
        FilesRecurse fsoSubFolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Using OBJECT seemed to have helped, thank you! I wonder why that is... The code that calls it simply calls ListTheFiles with the topLevel scripting folder as the parameter, ie. ListTheFiles(scriiptingObject.GetFolder("C:\Users\MyName\Documents\TopFolderName")